# repository not found in local server

Tags: git, bash

I learn basic operations with git and have this problem. I have my apache server as localhost:8080. I have repositories:

1. 'C:\apache\localhost\www\Machine2.git'.
2. 'C:\Programs\GitRepositories\Video2'.

I wrote 'http://localhost:8080/Machine2.git/' in browser, and the browser get to me fine answer with catalog of files.
In Git Bash of 'Machine2.git' I wrote:

```
# Rustam@RUSTAM_PC /C/apache/localhost/www/Machine2.git
$ git --bare init
# Initialized empty Git repository in c://apache/localhost/www/Machine2.git

# Rustam@RUSTAM_PC /C/Programs/GitRepositories/Video2
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial"
# [master (root-commit) ed08a791 Initial
# 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
# create mode 100644 Readme
$ git remote add origin http://localhost:8080/Machine2.git/
$ git push origin master 
# fatal: repository 'http://localhost:8080/Machine2.git/' not found
```

I have no idea. Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer. I open properties of Machine2 and set common access to all. Copy link to this directory.

1.delete Video2 folder;
2.create again Video2 folder at that path
3.open Bash and wrote code again.

```
$ git init    
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial"
$ git remote add origin //RUSTAM_PC/Machine2
$ git push origin master 
# Counting objects: 3, done.
# Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 223 bytes | 0 bytes/s. done.
# Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
# To //RUSTAM_PC/Machine2
# * [new branch] master -> master
```

Thanks to all!